# Split large log file into pieces based on date

Tags: text-processing, awk, split

I am trying to work out a Linux command to split a large log file into pieces based on date.

Using [How to split existing apache logfile by month?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11713978/how-to-split-existing-apache-logfile-by-month/11714105#11714105) as a starting point, I tried:

```
awk '{ split($4,array,"/"); print > array[2] ".txt" }' TestLog.txt
```

On my sample TestLog.txt with entries for May, Jun, and Jul of different years, this created text files May.txt, Jun.txt and Jul.txt:

In order to understand the values in the arrays, I eliminated the output file, and displayed the array values using:

```
awk '{ split($4,array,"/"); print  array[1] "  "  array[2] "  " array[3] "  " array[4] }' TestLog.txt
```

Where the first 2 lines of TestLog.txt are:

```
124.115.5.11 - - [30/May/2011:23:21:37 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 206492 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322;TencentTraveler)"
58.61.164.39 - - [31/May/2011:00:36:35 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 206492 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322;TencentTraveler)"
```

This resulted in `[30  May  2011:23:21:37`     for the first line in the file.

The results were very confusing to me.  In particular:

1. Why is `array[1]` equal to `[30` and not `124.115.5.11 - - [30` ?
2. Why is `array[3]` equal to `2011:23:21:37` and not `2011:00:36:35 -0500] "GET`?
3. Why is `array[4]` null?
4. What should the value of `array[0]` be?

Comment: Why did you choose to split `$4`?

Comment: I just used what had been specified at the link I cited.  I assumed it was specifying that the line should be split into 4 pieces.  Based on the explanation below, I now understand that $4 gabbed the 4th string ([30/May/2011:23:21:37) for further spitting.

Answer (score 3):

Lets take the first line:

```
124.115.5.11 - - [30/May/2011:23:21:37 -0500] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 206492 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322;TencentTraveler)"
```

and the crucial part of the `awk` snippet:

```
awk '{ split($4,array,"/") ...
```

Here what is happening:

- `awk` runs and splits the line on the spaces (default field separator)
- `4`*th* field in the line is additionally being split on `/` character
- the result of the split is put into the `array`
- later on the whole line is printed to the file named as a second subfield (`array[2]`) of the 4th field

so `$4` field initially contained `[30/May/2011:23:21:37`, and after split we have

```
array[1]=[30
array[2]=May
array[3]=2011:23:21:37
```

There is no `array[4]`, because there the `4`th field doesn't contain `4`th "subfield" and there is no `array[0]` because in `awk` array indexes start from 1.

Comment: Aha, I couldn't understand what he was trying to do.  So in this case he *could* just use `awk -F/ '{ print > $2 ".txt" }' TestLog.txt`.

Comment: @Wildcard very likely, if it is guarantee that there are no `/` before date (judging from the link to SO thats the case).

Comment: I wondered if spit had a default delimiter of space.  So those splits are basically being ignored, and the 4th string, (delimitered by spaces) is then split using / as the delimiter.  Then how can I extract the year (2011) also?

Comment: @Mike You can add `:` as a field separator: `awk -F '[/:]' '{print "Month: "$2", year: "$3}'`